# Keep correct size of embed video in TinyMce

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, tinymce-4

I want to add embed media in TinyMce with media plugin. When I add an embed video for example with specific size value, when I save the post, the width is not correct. The following HTML is created:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XlpTLDulFe8" width="100" height="100" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

But infortunatly, i've the folowing CSS (mdl CSS) that overload my width-size:

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

I want to use instead a `max-width:100%;` for keep iFrame width if it isn't superior to 100%

How can I disable the width property for iFrame created by TinyMce ? I've tried to get the HtmlElement for remove property and set another but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, this isn't the clever one but this still works well. I apply the css property to the parent `<p>` of the `<iframe>` (all iframe are put in `<p>` tag)

I use the following function

```
public correctWidthIframe(html: string) {
    let regex = /<p[^>]*>(<iframe*[^>]+(width=*[^height]*height="[0-9]*")[^>]*><\/iframe><\/p>)/g;
    return html.replace(regex, (match, p1, p2) => {
        let dimension = p2.match(/[0-9]+/g);
        let style: string = '<p style="max-width:'+dimension.shift()+'px;">'; // only width is wrong
        return style + p1;
    });
}
```

I use this function when i want to create and modify message that contain embedVideo.