# Unwrap p tags from images in TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Every inline element in TinyMCE is wrapped in `p` tags by default. Completely understandable and needed for what i want to do.

But only for the `img` tags i would like to remove the surrounding `p` tags.

I have tried to do it with JavaScript by using the events of the plugin, but every time, at the end, the `p` tags were there.

Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried to do it with JavaScript", can you show us what you've done?

Comment: I have used the following event https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#postprocess in order to take the content, convert it in jquery object do the adjustments and set the new data but with no success. I'm at home now and i don't have code sample in front of me.

Comment: Could you please share  your solution  how did you resolve it?

Comment: @Shad Unfortunately i do not have access to this project anymore and i cannot see what i have done. But i think Sabri's answer is a good start for resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using a regular expression that will clean the surrounding `p` tag.

I've did a similar stuff for correct width of my embed video. [You can found the solution to my problem here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697833/keep-correct-size-of-embed-video-in-tinymce)I think that the regex you need look like the one i've use. Hope this help !

Comment: Hello Sabri, yes, this is exactly what i did at the end of the story!

Comment: @Makis Hi Could you please add your solution to here , how did you resolve the issue , this answer is for iframe regex, I am having same problem like you have.

Comment: @Shad I have answered above.